# Minor bug with voting for your own post

Tags: bug, voting, user-interface

Minor bug, found on all Stack Exchange sites I've checked.

When you downvote or upvote your own post, it reads "You can&#39;t vote for your own post"—as opposed to "You can't vote for your own post." -

[image: Popup with "You can't vote for your own post"]

Nothing major, just a minor visual bug, I think.

Comment: It is [*not* a minor bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417237/you-need-at-least-15-a-href-help-whats-reputationreputation-a-to-cast-a-v#comment903707_417237).